# django south is changing my boolean data on init

Tags: python, django, django-south

To output my database to json file I would usually do

```
python manage.py dumptdata --indent=4 > mydata.json
```

However upon executing the following two commands to setup south:

```
python manage.py schemamigration myproj --initial
python manage.py migrate myproj --fake
```

I noticed that two of my booleans in mytable for an entry were switched from FALSE to TRUE! I see that from my GUI Web Interface interacting with the database however to more closely compare what changed and got corrupted I'd like to compare json to json but with south enabled I can no longer use the above command as it tells me

```
Not synced (use migrations):
 - myproj
```

My table that had entries affected is below, I could have more affected data that I have not uncovered.

```
class MyConfig(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    myConfigName = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    myA = models.ForeignKey(MyA)
    myB = models.ForeignKey(MyB)
    myBoolA = models.BooleanField()
    myBoolB = models.BooleanField()
    myBoolC = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'myA', 'myB')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s_%s_%s' % (self.myA.name, self.myB.name, self.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`schemamigration` and `migrate --fake` don't modify the database. Do you have any initial_data fixture that could be reloaded when migrating? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/initial-data/

Try to migrate with:

```
python manage.py migrate --no-initial-data
```

see [south doc](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/commands.html) for more info about options

Comment: Thanks luc! I think that might be the issue that it's reloating the fixture, how can I prevent a migration from reloading fixture, it seems to me counter intuitive since for me south was a way to keep my data and change the models, if it reloads fixtures then it's not keeping my data...

Comment: update the answer. Don't forget to accept, if this is the right answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that either an --initial or a --fake should alter the database at all, so I'm surprised that it would modify data. In terms of why you're getting the "Not synced (use migrations)" error, I think it's likely because you faked the initial migration.

Try un-migrating the --fake and re-applying the initial migration with

```
python manage.py migrate --fake zero
python manage.py migrate
```

Then, you should be able to do the dumptdata